# Cannot be resolved or is not a field error when import on new computer

Tags: eclipse, subclipse

I have just installed eclipse on my new laptop. After importing a project from Subclipse SVN, my project has the "cannot be resolved or is not a field" error which makes me unable to run the project at all. This does not occur in my old laptop when I imported the same project. I have 17 errors all revolving this "cannot be resolved or is not a field" error. Here are more details of the error: 
layout cannot be resolved or is not a field 
id cannot be resolved or is not a field 
login_button cannot be resolved or is not a field 
logout_button cannot be resolved or is not a field

I suspect it has something to do with the Eclipse settings. But I have the necessary settings configured: installed ADT plugin and Subclipse. Do you know what is wrong? Do i need to set any Environment variables for eclipse?

Comment: did you already `clean` your project already?